# missing Assembly refence in mvc3 while i'm running this error occur

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, compiler-errors

I got the below error while running my application:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'FacebookApplication' does not exist in   the namespace 'Facebook' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Can you poste some of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have included a reference to it in your project references.

In **Solution Explorer** scroll to your **References** section and check if its there.

If its not **Right click** and choose **Add Reference** and then navigate to whereever the file is located.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already add required reference files after that also it shows same error